# how to use 2 mod_rewrites in single .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I use 2 mod_rewrite blocks?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.zaks\.ir$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?id=%1 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I use the above code blocks in 1 htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the blocks very easily, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.zaks\.ir$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?id=%1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Mod_rewrite will process the conditions until it gets to a rule. Then it starts over with the next conditions until it gets to another rule. The conditions in your first block won't affect the conditions in your second block because there is a `RewriteRule` at the end of the first set of conditions.

Comment: I want this address
param1.mysite.com/param2
I turned to this address.
mysite.com?p=param1&url=param2

However, the code above could
Friends I 'm grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

I want this address

```
 param1.mysite.com/param2
```

I turned to this address

```
 mysite.com?p=param1&url=param2
```

However, the code above could Friends I 'm grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

i find ......

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.ir [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).mysite.ir [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=%1&url=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```